# How to get the data array from scatter_matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using the `scatter_matrix` of `pandas`, and I was wondering how do I get the 2D array plotted on each scatter matrix? Also, how do I recognize which `AxesSubplot` of the output is which matrix on the output graph?

Answer (score 2):

`scatter_matrix` is a convenience function of `pandas`, from the `pandas.plotting` submodule. While [the documentation is scarce](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot) (and the [docstring](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4a6c3c56f54bf1f85f35aaae76dc76e7cf567b8f/pandas/plotting/_misc.py#L85-L126) is only a bit more helpful), the example makes it quite straightforward to understand how it works. Consider the example in the documentation:

```
import numpy as np # only needed for the example input
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
axs = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6,6), diagonal='kde')
axs[0,0].get_figure().show() # or import and call matplotlib.pyplot.show
```

[image: example scatter_matrix output]

Note the labels on the bottom and left axes: those indicate which columns of the input dataframe are plotted against one another in the given row/column. In the first column of plots the x axis corresponds to `df.a`, in the second row of plots the y axis corresponds to `df.b` etc. (and in the diagonals either densities or histograms of the respective columns are plotted). Consequently, transposed elements in the plot matrix correspond to a swap of the x and y data, i.e. reflection of the plot with respect to the x=y line. If you take a close look at the above figure you'll see that this is indeed the case.

In other words, you don't need to figure out the data from the individual axes, since you have direct control of your input data. In the off-diagonal axes `axs[i,j]` the x data are given by `df[df.columns[j]]` and the y data are given by `df[df.columns[i]]`. Here's a quick kludge to help visualize the order:

```
axs = scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, figsize=(6,6), diagonal='kde')
for i in range(axs.shape[0]):
    for j in range(axs.shape[1]):
        if i == j:
            continue
        axs[i,j].set_title('x: {}, y: {}'.format(df.columns[j],df.columns[i]),
                           position=(0.5,0.5))
```

[image: example scatter_matrix output with annotations showing the x and y sources for each off-diagonal plot]

So while it would be possible to dig into the entrails of each of the `AxesSubplot` objects and extract the data from there, it's much simpler to use the respective columns of `df` directly. One exception are the diagonals: in case of a kernel density plot (assuming that the `diagonal='kde'` keyword was passed to `scatter_matrix`) you don't have direct access to the underlying data. In that case you can extract the lines from the diagonal `AxesSubplots`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
index = 0
xdat,ydat = axs[index,index].get_lines()[0].get_data() # example for diagonal [0,0]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xdat,ydat,'-')
plt.xlabel(df.columns[index])
plt.ylabel('density')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't answer my question (or I've failed to understand the answer) - how do I get the 2D arrays plotted in each subplot? I'm new to this library, so while it might be straightforward from your answer - I don't understand it. I'd like to use the correlation graphs, not the DataFrame of inputs.

Comment: My point was exactly to use the dataframe :) As I said, you can do what you want directly, but your question sounded like a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you edit your question and explain _why_ you really need to do this, I can show you how.

Comment: I'd like to use the XY plots as heat-maps - in the drawing you posted, the more dark it is, the hotter

Comment: @shakedzy that doesn't answer why you can't use the underlying dataframe directly. Or if you mean that you want to use the darkness from the overlapping semi-transparent circles somehow, that won't be possible to do, but there's surely a better way to do that. Really, what is it you're actually trying to solve here? (The X in your XY problem;)

Comment: I use the scatter_matrix to find correlation of different features of users. I mark on these plots all the known fraud devices I have, and I wish to create a heat-map to use on unknown devices, and see how close they are to the fraud behavior